# custom HID device no longer supported by WebUSB?

Tags: webusb

A few week ago, WebUSB was able to communicate with my custom HID device on both MAC and Window platform.

Now it seems that latest Chrome update (65.0.3325.162) has removed this support on Window platform.
https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/951635

Can someone please confirm this? 
What would be the solution for custom HID device to work with WebUSB then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. On all platforms a device advertising the HID protocol will be claimed by the system HID driver and should not be claimed by a site using the WebUSB API.

If you want to connect to an HID interface you will need to modify the device so that the interface is no longer marked as HID.

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/LZXocaeCwDw) for more information on this policy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's sad to hear that :(
Chrome is removing chrome apps on all platforms except chrome OS, so I guess chrome.hid won't be available anymore. So there is no way for custom HID device to work with web. Am I right?

Comment: That is correct for the moment. Since I work on web standards and am always interested in what new use cases people are interested in, may I ask what kind of device this is? If it is "custom HID" is it a human interface device or is it some other kind of peripheral?

Comment: in addition to normal HID functionality (turn on/off LEDs), the device also uses the HID interface to upgrade its FW

Comment: @ReillyGrant As you are looking for usecases: many speciallized input devices are hid devices. I am trying to get a footswitch connected to a webapp which does not work for said reason.

Comment: @ReillyGrant We have developed several specialised HID devices, which send arbitrary data and may be configured or be FW upgraded through USB. We could have used a CDC class (and could still change to CDC), but the HID class has the significant advantage that the end user does not have to install any drivers. Our apps are currently Chrome Apps so we are looking for a migration path to Progressive Web Apps... Even if we used CDC I am not aware of any support for serial in web apps.

Answer (score 0):

As a "workaround" on Windows, you can tell the OS to use WinUSB driver instead of HIDUSB as suggested in http://gerritniezen.com/2017/10/connecting-to-usb-devices-with-your-browser/

I used the Zadig tool to force the use of the WinUSB driver and it works for me. I can communicate with my HID device from Chrome and WebUSB.

On my laptop, this HID device will not be accessed by the HIDUSB driver anymore as long as the driver switch has not been reverted (so some applications cannot communicate with it anymore). But on other laptop, it still works as a standard USB HID device.

I am still looking for a way/workaround to allow Chrome to claim directly the HID device...

Comment: You're right. Using Zadig or an inf file would help. But it's not convenient for end users. I think there will be no solution as Reilly Grant has confirmed in his reply to this post